Import Array to Godot via CSV
I'm currently making a game in Godot using CSV tables to help keep track of things.  Most stuff works, except when I want to import a column as an array.  How would I format this array in a CSV so that it imports like this?
"["Civ (Fishing)","Civ (Trade)","Civ (Transport)"]"

I think the plugin I'm using to import CSVs automatically puts double quotes around the array, which is fine, as I can convert an array as a string to a regular array, but it keeps messing up and does this:
"[\"Civ (Fishing)\",\"Civ (Trade)\",\"Civ (Transport)\"]"

if I do this:
"["Civ (Fishing)","Civ (Trade)","Civ (Transport)"]"

and it does this:
"[Civ (Fishing)", "Civ (Trade)", "Civ (Transport)]"

if I do this:
[Civ (Fishing),Civ (Trade),Civ (Transport)]

I think this is less a Godot problem and more a CSV one. I saw that there's the whole double quote to escape double quote thing, but I'm not sure where to put it those quotes here.
Any help would be appreciated!

Never mind, I'm just...le dumb.
While it DOES import this
"["Civ (Fishing)","Civ (Trade)","Civ (Transport)"]"

as this
"[\"Civ (Fishing)\",\"Civ (Trade)\",\"Civ (Transport)\"]"

Godot's str_to_var() function translates it just fine to an array, and I was getting too worried about how the original imported data looked instead of checking if it actually worked.  I must have been incorrectly calling it this whole time. :/
